# Dynamically delete v-for iteration on overflow

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, overflow

I have this code

```html
<template>   
  <v-row v-if="instaFeed" grid-list-xs class="pl-2 pr-2">
    <v-col
      v-for="index in 12"
      :key="index"
      class="mt-3 pl-1 pr-1"
      cols="1">
      <a :href="instaFeed.data[index-1].permalink" target="__blank">
        <v-img
          :src="instaFeed.data[index-1].media_url"
        />
      </a>
    </v-col>
  </v-row> 
</template>
```

When the screen is 1920*1080, images perfectly suit to my page.

As soon as I try to resize the page, the images start to overflow on the right.

Do you know to way to instantly hide my last image on overflow ?

I know that vuetify breakpoints won't be enough as it will let the images overflow on some screens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/

Comment: Why not make it responsive rather than hide it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

I added `overflow-y-auto` class to the `v-row`.
Then i made the `v-for` using a computed prop returning an index depending on the viewport.
This way I get to display the right amount of images with the max size they can get, without overflow.

Here's my code.

```
<template>
  <v-row v-if="instaFeed" justify="center" grid-list-xs class="pl-2 pr-2 overflow-y-auto">
    <v-col
      v-for="index in imagesLoop"
      :key="index"
      cols="3"
      sm="2"
      md="1"
      class="mt-3 pl-1 pr-1"
    >
      <a :href="instaFeed.data[index-1].permalink" target="__blank">
        <v-card>
          <v-img
            :src="instaFeed.data[index-1].media_url"
          />
        </v-card>
      </a>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

And the computed prop looks like this

```
computed: {
    imagesLoop () {
      switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
        case 'xs' : return 4
        case 'sm' : return 6
        case 'md' : return 12
        case 'lg' : return 12
        case 'xl' : return 12
      }
      return null
    }
  },
```